# iOS Simple XML Parsing For Weather

Tags: ios, xml, xcode, rss, gdataxml

I have done xml parsing before using some guides from Ray Wenderlich, but those are usually for when there are multiple items involved.  I am working on having an app simply display weather conditions at a given time, and the feed's XML just has conditions for time checked.  Here is the feed in question:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
        <rss version="2.0" xmlns:yweather="http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0" xmlns:geo="http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#">
            <channel>

<title>Yahoo! Weather - Montgomery, AL</title>
<link>http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/Montgomery__AL/*http://weather.yahoo.com/forecast/USAL0375_f.html</link>
<description>Yahoo! Weather for Montgomery, AL</description>
<language>en-us</language>
<lastBuildDate>Thu, 03 Jan 2013 11:55 am CST</lastBuildDate>
<ttl>60</ttl>
<yweather:location city="Montgomery" region="AL"   country="United States"/>
<yweather:units temperature="F" distance="mi" pressure="in" speed="mph"/>
<yweather:wind chill="43"   direction="0"   speed="5" />
<yweather:atmosphere humidity="66"  visibility="10"  pressure="30.26"  rising="2" />
<yweather:astronomy sunrise="6:46 am"   sunset="4:52 pm"/>
<image>
<title>Yahoo! Weather</title>
<width>142</width>
<height>18</height>
<link>http://weather.yahoo.com</link>
<url>http://l.yimg.com/a/i/brand/purplelogo//uh/us/news-wea.gif</url>
</image>
<item>
<title>Conditions for Montgomery, AL at 11:55 am CST</title>
<geo:lat>32.38</geo:lat>
<geo:long>-86.3</geo:long>
<link>http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/Montgomery__AL/*http://weather.yahoo.com/forecast/USAL0375_f.html</link>
<pubDate>Thu, 03 Jan 2013 11:55 am CST</pubDate>
<yweather:condition  text="Mostly Cloudy"  code="28"  temp="46"  date="Thu, 03 Jan 2013 11:55 am CST" />
<description><![CDATA[
<img src="http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/28.gif"/><br />
<b>Current Conditions:</b><br />
Mostly Cloudy, 46 F<BR />
<BR /><b>Forecast:</b><BR />
Thu - Partly Cloudy. High: 50 Low: 31<br />
Fri - Sunny. High: 57 Low: 35<br />
<br />
<a href="http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/Montgomery__AL/*http://weather.yahoo.com/forecast/USAL0375_f.html">Full Forecast at Yahoo! Weather</a><BR/><BR/>
(provided by <a href="http://www.weather.com" >The Weather Channel</a>)<br/>
]]></description>
<yweather:forecast day="Thu" date="3 Jan 2013" low="31" high="50" text="Partly Cloudy" code="30" />
<yweather:forecast day="Fri" date="4 Jan 2013" low="35" high="57" text="Sunny" code="32" />
<guid isPermaLink="false">USAL0375_2013_01_04_7_00_CST</guid>
</item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

Basically, all I need for the app is the current temperature and conditions, which under the item tag is contained within yweather:conditions tag.  Using GDataXML, what would be simplest way of getting this info and setting an NSString equal to it?

Right now, I'm using some complex stuff from Ray's tutorial with asihttprequest and blocks for sorting and putting it all into an NSMutableArray, but I'm fairly certain it doesn't need be that complex now.

Answer (score 0):

I like TBXML for straightforward parsing: http://www.tbxml.co.uk/TBXML/TBXML_Free.html .